# Canvas Infinite Scroll mapping object location

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

Trying to get infinite looping scrolling to work in KonvaJS, so there would be a grid of say 24 items, which would just keep scrolling over and over.

Thanks to @lavrton the basic grid is working, but adding items means that they don't stay in place on the redraw. Im guessing it relates to:

```
 fill: grid[indexX][indexY],
```

Any ideas how I can map the text to the blocks?

```
 const stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        draggable: true
    });

    const layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    const WIDTH = 100;
    const HEIGHT = 100;

    const grid = [
        ['red', 'yellow'],
        ['green', 'blue']
    ];

    const blocks = [
        { w: 150, h: 150 , background: "white" , image: "/img/test2.png" , fullImage: false, title: "" , text: "" },
        { w: 150, h: 150 , background: "white" , image: "/img/person-icon.png" ,  fullImage: false ,title: "" , text: "" },
        { w: 150, h: 150 , background: "#575756" , image: "" ,  fullImage: false, title: "Title" , text: "" },
        { w: 300, h: 300 , background: "white" , image: "/img/test.png", fullImage: true, title: "" , text: "" }

    ];

        function checkShapes() {
        const startX = Math.floor((-stage.x() - stage.width()) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;
        const endX = Math.floor((-stage.x() + stage.width() * 2) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;

        const startY = Math.floor((-stage.y() - stage.height()) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;
        const endY = Math.floor((-stage.y() + stage.height() * 2) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;



        var i = 0;
        for(var x = startX; x < endX; x += WIDTH) {
            for(var y = startY; y < endY; y += HEIGHT) {

                if(i === 4)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }

                const indexX = Math.abs(x / WIDTH) % grid.length;
                const indexY = Math.abs(y / HEIGHT) % grid[0].length;

                layer.add(new Konva.Rect({
                    x,
                    y,
                    width: WIDTH,
                    height: HEIGHT,
                    fill: grid[indexX][indexY],
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 4
                }))

                if(blocks[i].title != ""){

                    var complexText = new Konva.Text({
                        x,
                        y,
                        text: "TEST TEXT",
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                        fill: 'white',
                        width: WIDTH,
                        height: HEIGHT,
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        align : "center"
                    });

                    layer.add(complexText);

                }



            }
            i++
        }

    }

    checkShapes();
    layer.draw();

    stage.on('dragend', () => {
        layer.destroyChildren();
        checkShapes();
        layer.draw();
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kiksy/jqo2h3dx/2/

Comment: You are making illusion of infinite scroll. You need `world` and `camera` to make it work. Right know you are showing stuff at coordination that depends on the size of `canvas` so whatever is outside won't work. It's easier to use something else than KonvaJS in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

The issue is the calculation of *`i`*. It needs to be based on the values of `indexX` and `indexY`

Something like this:

```
//maps from 0 to 3
const i = indexX * 2 + indexY;
```

When observing your blocks array, only one has title and it is at the index of `2` which (depending on your perspective) corresponds to the green color.

```
const i = 1 * 2 + 0; //index 2
```

Why `* 2` ? It's just hard coded, but corresponds to the inner grid array length which is 2.

```
(Ex: grid[0].length)
```

### Full solution:

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  draggable: true
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


const WIDTH = 100;
const HEIGHT = 100;

const grid = [
  ['red', 'yellow'],
  ['green', 'blue']
];

const blocks = [{
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/test2.png",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/person-icon.png",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "#575756",
    image: "",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "Title",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 300,
    h: 300,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/test.png",
    fullImage: true,
    title: "",
    text: ""
  }

];

function checkShapes() {
  const startX = Math.floor((-stage.x() - stage.width()) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;
  const endX = Math.floor((-stage.x() + stage.width() * 2) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;

  const startY = Math.floor((-stage.y() - stage.height()) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;
  const endY = Math.floor((-stage.y() + stage.height() * 2) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;



  for (var x = startX; x < endX; x += WIDTH) {
    for (var y = startY; y < endY; y += HEIGHT) {


      const indexX = ((x / WIDTH) + grid.length * WIDTH) % grid.length;
      const indexY = ((y / HEIGHT) + grid[0].length * HEIGHT) % grid[0].length;

      //maps from 0 to 3
      const i = indexX * 2 + indexY;

      layer.add(new Konva.Rect({
        x,
        y,
        width: WIDTH,
        height: HEIGHT,
        fill: grid[indexX][indexY],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      }))

      if (blocks[i].title != "") {

        var complexText = new Konva.Text({
          x,
          y,
          text: "TEST TEXT",
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          fill: 'white',
          width: WIDTH,
          height: HEIGHT,
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          align: "center"
        });

        layer.add(complexText);

      }
    }
  }

}

checkShapes();
layer.draw();

stage.on('dragend', () => {
  layer.destroyChildren();
  checkShapes();
  layer.draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.6.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### Full Solution with Red and Blue having titles:

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  draggable: true
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


const WIDTH = 100;
const HEIGHT = 100;

const grid = [
  ['red', 'yellow'],
  ['green', 'blue']
];

const blocks = [{
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/test2.png",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "Title",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/person-icon.png",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 150,
    h: 150,
    background: "#575756",
    image: "",
    fullImage: false,
    title: "",
    text: ""
  },
  {
    w: 300,
    h: 300,
    background: "white",
    image: "/img/test.png",
    fullImage: true,
    title: "Title",
    text: ""
  }

];

function checkShapes() {
  const startX = Math.floor((-stage.x() - stage.width()) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;
  const endX = Math.floor((-stage.x() + stage.width() * 2) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;

  const startY = Math.floor((-stage.y() - stage.height()) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;
  const endY = Math.floor((-stage.y() + stage.height() * 2) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;



  for (var x = startX; x < endX; x += WIDTH) {
    for (var y = startY; y < endY; y += HEIGHT) {


      const indexX = ((x / WIDTH) + grid.length * WIDTH) % grid.length;
      const indexY = ((y / HEIGHT) + grid[0].length * HEIGHT) % grid[0].length;
      //maps from 0 to 3
      const i = indexX * 2 + indexY;

      layer.add(new Konva.Rect({
        x,
        y,
        width: WIDTH,
        height: HEIGHT,
        fill: grid[indexX][indexY],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      }))

      if (blocks[i].title != "") {

        var complexText = new Konva.Text({
          x,
          y,
          text: "TEST TEXT",
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          fill: 'white',
          width: WIDTH,
          height: HEIGHT,
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          align: "center"
        });

        layer.add(complexText);

      }
    }
  }

}

checkShapes();
layer.draw();

stage.on('dragend', () => {
  layer.destroyChildren();
  checkShapes();
  layer.draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.6.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### Mirror Issue Solution:

This is directly caused because of the following calculations:

```
const indexX = Math.abs(x / WIDTH) % grid.length;
const indexY = Math.abs(y / HEIGHT) % grid[0].length;
```

and solved with:

```
const indexX = ((x/WIDTH) + grid.length * WIDTH )  % grid.length;
const indexY = ((y/HEIGHT) + grid.length * HEIGHT) % grid[0].length;
```

When you calculate colors you base it off of your grid array:

```
  ['red', 'yellow', 'pink' ]
  ['green', 'blue' , 'gray' ]
  ['orange', 'blue' , 'black']
```

And when you advance logically down or right (positive values) there are no issues, when you move up or left (negative values) everything goes nuts because you calculate indexX and indexY with Math.abs.

So for example, a red box located [-1,-1] doesn't match any color in the grid. Based on your formula, it'll simply choose the 'blue' color when in fact it should be the 'black' color.

Comment: Wow thanks! That answers my question. I've expanded on it here: https://jsfiddle.net/kiksy/hpduwr09/3/ you can see that the 2 titled blocks stay in the correct order when dragging down or left, but draggin up or  right means they go out of order. I assume becuase it needs to draw in reverse for a negative x/y drag?

Comment: I think I understood that part, the issue is the redraw on a up or left drag (so a minus) seems to redraw in the wrong order, even with the updated * 2 .see https://jsfiddle.net/kiksy/hpduwr09/10/ . Notice the 4 numbered blocks go out of order. Thanks for your help with this. Its been melting my brain for so long now.

Comment: ah yes! I've just been playing around with trying to adjust those values based on the drag direction! Your solution is much simpler! Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi! is it possible to have different sizes with a margin between the boxes?